# Classification of the group action

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, orthogonal-groups, isometry-groups

Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $O(n)$ such that $\mathbb R^n/G$ is isometric to $\mathbb R^{n-2} \times \mathbb R_+$. Can we have a classification of $G$ up to conjugation?

Comment: Probably up to conjugation is more interesting. Nevertheless $G$ should have 1-dimensional orbits and this should be quite restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

The generic orbits are 1-dimensional.

The action might have fixed points that correspond to the boundary of the space of orbits $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}\times\mathbb{R}_+$,
or these orbits are 1-dimensional as well.

In the first case, it is a subaction of $O(2)$ acting on the first factor of $\mathbb{R}^2\oplus\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$.

In the second case, the action is an extension of $\mathbb{R}$-action by parallel translations.

Comment: Oops, since it is a subgroup of $O(n)$, you only have the first case.

Comment: There are plenty of other possible actions (e.g., $SO(2)$ acting diagonally on $R^2\oplus R^2$), in many possible ways. How do you discard them?

Comment: @YCor I only claim that it is a subgroup of $O(2)$ that acts on the first factor of $\mathbb{R}^2\oplus\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$. Since the orbit is 1-dimensional, it has to be either $SO(2)$ or $O(2)$.

Comment: Why not $O(2)$ or $SO(2)$ $\times$ a finite group?

Comment: @YCor if a group acting nontrivially on the $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$-factor, then the quotient cannot have an isometric copy of $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$.